android aosp launcher3 icon broken
I'm using AOSP Launcher3, and I've placed all icons on the first page. However, I occasionally encounter broken icons after restarting the system, as shown in the picture. I've only used methods documented in AOSP Launcher for this customization. How can I fix this issue?

Methods of solving the issue
